# Show Mac devices in NSOpenPanel/NSSavePanel

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

For a given NSOpenPanel or NSSavePanel you can set a directory to show with:

```
[panel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/SomeFolder"]];
```

There you can set whatever path you like, but how can you show the Network or Mac devices?

[Mac devices view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWOTF.png)

[Network devices view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zr58x.png)

Comment: I doubt that the Network (Cmd+Shift+K) and Computer (aka devices, Cmd+Shift+C) views of Finder represent any real file system directory to use with NSOpenPanel. Do you have any examples of apps that do that?

Comment: No, I do not have any examples. I also thought this might be not possible.

Comment: It's a bit hacky but you can send Cmd+Shift+K to the panel using `performKeyEquivalent:`.

Comment: That one will unselect the item previously specified with `setDirectoryURL:`, but worth a try. Do you have any sample code?